# ¿ Cómo guardarme 2 números seleccionados de 2 numberPicker en un dialog?

Tags: java, android, diálogo, numberpicker

Tengo 2 `numberPicker` como en la imagen adjunta bajo, y cuando selecciono `ok` después no se me guarda lo que he selecionado , pues la primera columna son **minutos** y la segunda son **segundos** y se tienen que guardar como tal pero no consigo como aunar eso. Es la 1a vez que hago un `numberPicker` doble y guardar lo que selecciono (aun siendo 1 o dos línea de código) no me aclaro al implementarlas. ¿ Alguna ayuda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void setDuracionAsaltos() {




    LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

    final NumberPicker aNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    aNumberPicker.setMaxValue(15);
    aNumberPicker.setMinValue(1);

    final NumberPicker aNumberPickerA = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    aNumberPickerA.setMaxValue(59);
    aNumberPickerA.setMinValue(1);
   // aNumberPickerA.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Tea Cup", "Glass","Plate","Small Plate","Cutlets","Medium","Piece","Katori","Balls","Serving","egg"});

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    numPicerParams.weight = 1;


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams qPicerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    qPicerParams.weight = 1;



    LL.setLayoutParams(params);
    LL.addView(aNumberPicker,numPicerParams);
    LL.addView(aNumberPickerA,qPicerParams);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Select the number");
    builder.setView(LL);


    builder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Log.e("","New Quantity Value : "+ aNumberPicker.getValue());
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas noches amigo, tienes mal los botones, checa mi codigo

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(primero);
    builder.setTitle("Cantidad de Glucosa");
    builder.setView(LL);

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```